# Laravel managing queue supervisor for production and staging on single server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, queue

I have two sites on a single digital ocean droplet, production and staging. I've installed queue supervisor according to the docs: `sudo apt-get install supervisor` and configured two configuration files inside `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` as follows:

laravel-worker.conf:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/app.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

laravel-worker-staging.conf:

```
[program:laravel-worker-staging]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/test.app.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/test.app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Once I'm done testing I will disable the server block for test.app.com to prevent random users to visit the site . Do I need to do anything with queue supervisor because it will still be running in the background for the test site or maybe the laravel-worker-staging.conf to prevent it from unnecessarily using up server resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I could just issue the following command:

```
supervisorctl stop laravel-worker-staging
```